# Serve Java application running on one port via nginx server running on another

Tags: nginx

I have a PHP running on a current `nginx` running over HTTPS (443). I also have a Java application running over HTTPS port 8443.

Is there a way that I can expose the Java application over HTTPS (443)? Maybe using `proxy_pass` or something (see [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) e.g.)?

My aim is to have both applications available over a single port by the user going to:

- https://server/ - Standard Web pages
- https://server/java - Redirects to the Java app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is really well-covered "on the internet": research "reverse proxy" and "server block".

Your problem is that a single IP address can only have a single process listening on a port – so it's *either* nginx **or** your Java application.

Now, you can configure nginx to react to HTTP requests for a specific *domain* (which is not an IP address, but a name service entry, say "yourhost.com") differently than for others. Then, you could have two "virtual" domains:

java.server and just server, and depending on which your client connects to, nginx will either handle the request itself (leading to your PHP being executed) or act as a reverse proxy (indeed with `proxy_pass`, but that's far from the only way of doing things).

Generally, beware that this *necessarily* involves unpacking TLS (otherwise, nginx can't know the domain being asked for) and re-packing your HTTP content - i.e. the TLS certificate of the Java application never reaches the client. That might often be good, but if your client needs to establish trust to the Java application, it's no option.

If this is an internal network, simply get another IP address. Internal IP addresses don't cost anything. If this is an external service, think about whether you can maybe move towards IPv6 only (where you usually get a whole block of IP addresses at once, and this problem doesn't arise, because each service can have their own), or whether you can put things on different IPv4 addresses.